# Stop Duplicate Block IDs from being assigned to Different LVM2 Logical Volumes

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

Ubuntu MATE 16.10 i386 System Using Grub2 / LVM2

GOAL
Stop Ubuntu filesystem from assigning Duplicate Block ID to two different LVM2 Logical Volumes.

QUESTION
What needs to be done to accomplish the goal?

```
One HDD partitioned MSDOS

Partition 1 WindowsXP 32 Bit sda1
Partition 2 LVM2 PV sda2

LVM2 Physical Volume /dev/sda2
LVM2 Volume Group "ToshibaLinux_VG"
LVM2 Logical Volume "Boot_UbuntuMate1610_LV"
LVM2 Logical Volume "UMate1610_LV"

 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ToshibaLinux_VG/Boot_UbuntuMate1610_LV
  LV Name                Boot_UbuntuMate1610_LV
  VG Name                ToshibaLinux_VG
  LV UUID                qLhonZ-HGlu-UjkO-9kPe-VYRZ-OOES-rsE4p2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-mate, 2017-02-24 15:07:34 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
  Current LE             1536
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ToshibaLinux_VG/UMate1610_LV
  LV Name                UMate1610_LV
  VG Name                ToshibaLinux_VG
  LV UUID                q2GWTO-B4U9-nsEj-hsQ6-9Htp-1aXX-cpWhUG
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time Toshiba, 2017-02-24 22:40:41 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                25.00 GiB
  Current LE             6400
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

Ubuntu Filesystem Block IDs assigned to Logical Volumes
[terminal shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gQug.png)

Only one Logical Volume can be accessed by the files system as Block ID 64ddb.....
[caja filemanager shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI9ee.png)

Comment: How did you create the LVs? those don't look like the default names from the installer. Are you sure those aren't cached UUIDs (try running `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` to make sure)

Comment: The LVs were created by a GUI called "Logical Volume Management" package name system-config-lvm_1.1.18-3ubuntu1_all.deb from apt-get. The Boot_UbuntuMate1610_LV OS was installed from Live CD. An image (not snapshot) was made of Boot_UbuntuMate1610_LV OS and restored to UMate1610_LV with the intention of using UMate1610_LV to boot from and use as the main system. Since I posted I did a fresh install to UMate1610_LV, so I can't run the blkid with the -c switch as requested.  I know this issue will come up again and would still like to know how to stop the OS from assigning a duplicate UUID